# Word for "secondary part of a dish that soaks up the sauce of the primary part"

Tags: single-word-requests, food

A lot of dishes include a small amount of meat or fish or something else with a strong flavor, and then a large portion of rice or mashed potatoes or spaghetti, or something else that is comparatively flavorless. What's the word for that latter part?

Example usage:

> "The rice on my plate is the _____ for my meat"
>    "Here are some meat balls, with rice as their ______"

I'm not sure if English has a word for this. In Russian, there's the word "гарнир" ("garnir"), but the English word that sounds like it, "garnish", seems like a false cognate, because it means specifically a decorative extra part of a dish.

Comment: **main dish** accompanied by **side dishes**

Comment: "Side dish" is the best word I've ever found for "garnir". Still, I feel like "garnir" implies that it has to be right there next to the main dish, absorbing and diluting it, while "side dish" doesn't have that requirement - it could be literally in a separate plate or bowl on the side.

Comment: I think 'complement' is usually the word that would suit your examples.

Answer (score 2):

Potatoes, rice and pasta are often called **starchy foods**.

> Try to include them at every meal by basing your meals on **starchy foods such as potatoes, breads, pasta, rice, noodles or cereals** (more examples below).
>
> <sub>[British Nutrition Foundation](https://www.nutrition.org.uk/healthyliving/healthyeating/starchyfoods.html)</sub>

The rice /potatoes / pasta / dumplings that **accompany** the meat, are either an ingredient of the main dish, or an important **[accompaniment](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accompaniment)**. The Milanese dish [*osso buco*](http://www.foodrepublic.com/recipes/osso-buco-with-saffron-risotto-recipe/) is often **served with** saffron *risotto*.

A 1971 newspaper cooking [article](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1917&dat=19710505&id=FL0tAAAAIBAJ&sjid=5IkFAAAAIBAJ&pg=2305,943938&hl=en):

- *chicken and rice make a great duo for entertaining, ... served with a wine flavored cream sauce and the rice accompaniment ...*.

Modifying the OP's examples one could say

- Rice is the ideal [accompaniment to](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22accompanied+by+potatoes%22&tbm=bks) most savoury meat dishes
- Here's the meat [accompanied by potatoes](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22accompanied+by+potatoes%22&tbm=bks)

> **[accompany](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accompany)**   (Oxford Dictionaries)
>   2.1 Provide a complement or addition to
>
> Example: *The generous portion of shrimp was covered in a delicious spicy brown sauce and **accompanied** by a plain white bun.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be the *secondary part*.

**Staple food** — [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/staple-food.html)

> That is regularly consumed in a community or society and from which people obtain most or significant proportion of their calorie requirements.
>
> *"Rice is a staple food in many parts of the world. It is consumed as the main source of calories by millions of people every day."*

Comment: I'm looking for a word to use in this sort of context: "The rice on my plate is the <blank> for my meat", or "here are some meat balls, with rice as their <blank>". I don't think "staple" fits that.

Answer (score 0):

A **bed of rice** is what would soak up the sauce. Traditionally, garnishes *cleanse the palette* in preparation for dessert, and I think that is being confused with *soak up the sauce*, by either you or Google translate.

NVZ had it with, "**main dish** accompanied by **side dishes**":

"The rice on my plate is the *side dish* for my meat."
"Here are some meat balls, with rice as their *side*."

Unless you *are* talking about the supposedly tasteless and seemingly useless garnish *–them's fightin' words–* [I like parsley](https://restaurant-ingthroughhistory.com/2015/03/22/why-the-parsley-garnish-2/).

Comment: The "soak up the sauces" was my interpretation on the OP's *"..secondary dish that comes in a greater amount and dilutes/absorbs the strong flavor...."* The problem with *side dish* is that  it doesn't necessarily share the same plate as the main dish, and that is what the OP is specifically asking about. A salad is a side dish but it is served on a separate plate in restaurants.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - A side dish doesn't necessarily share the same plate as the main dish, but **a bed of** or whatever it's **served over** does. Using this method is most likely with the intention of flavoring your *side* with the sauce.

Comment: Rarely  heard of *a bed of pasta*, but **noodles as an accompaniment**, works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The original [trencher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trencher_(tableware)) was stale bread used as a plate, to collect sauce from the entree though it has evolved to be a shallow wooden bowl.  Today, you can still order soup in [bread bowls](https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/recipes/tuscan-white-bean-dip-in-a-bread-bowl.html) from midrange national branded chain restaurants.

Bread can also be used as a [sop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sop) and other starches put on a plate would similarly sop up the sauce.